# Create temporary branch during

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, pull-request

I have integration between Jenkins and Bitbucket to build branch and PR. I use for it Bitbucket Branch Source and Pipeline: Multibranch plugins in general. All working well, but I would like to modify current flow to with the next example:

1. I chop off a branch from develop with the name new-feature
2. Add change to new-feature branch
3. Create Pull Request new-feature -> develop
4. Here I would like modify flow - if my PR could be automerged, Bitbucket create some temporary branch with merge result (new-feature -> develop)
5. Jenkins build this branch
6. Build result reported back to my PR
7. When PR will be approved and merged with develop, this temporary branch is removed

In this case I would like to prevent situation, when some PR will be build without any problem but I got some unexpected error when Jenkins build develop with change from PR.

I would very much appreciate for any ideas how to realize it

Comment: What is the error ?? you need to post the issue if you want some kind of help

Comment: I would like to know, it's possible to merge source and target branch in PR to some temporary branch for build procedure.

I found variable BRANCH_NAME for target branch, like develop in my case and it's looks good. But BRANCH_NAME connected with PR number, like PR-9, not is new-feature, like in my case. If I could get name of real source branch from variable, I could try proceed with some bash script :)

Comment: Why do you want to merge, build and merge again ?? why do the extra step?? why not ensure that the forked code has the updated code always and then when a PR is done you can just build it and do a final merge

Comment: bcz I have such requirements :) Any way, I use sh during my pipeline to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 stage ('Merge') {

 sh "git fetch --no-tags --progress ${gitUrl} +refs/pull-requests/${env.CHANGE_ID}/from:refs/remotes/origin/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
 sh "git merge remotes/origin/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"

}
```